# How to show the original size of the image in imageview

Tags: android, camera, imageview

Im making an app where you can click on a button and take a photo, then after photo is taken i want to show it in a imageview.

i use this code for that:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);    

    Button b = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {           
            try {
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
            } catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Your device does not have a camera", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }    
        }           
    }); 

    send = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.button2);
    send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Uploading image...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            new uploadtoserver().execute();
        }           
    });
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
        if (data != null) {
            Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");               
            ImageView image = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.imageView1);  
            //image.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);  

            send.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);

            // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE URI FROM THE BITMAP
            Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getActivity(), thumbnail);
            // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE ACTUAL PATH
            finalFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(tempUri));

            Bitmap bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(finalFile.toString());

            image.setImageBitmap(bmImg);

            System.out.println(finalFile);
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the xml part of the imageview

but it is showing the image cropped and ugly(not the original size)

how to let it show the original size of the photo in the imageview?

Answer (score 0):

The image data returned in an `Intent` extra is a scaled down version of the captured image, suitable for a thumbnail.  The full-size image is written to the file location you passed as the `EXTRA_OUTPUT` Uri in the request.  If you want to work with the full image itself, you need to look there.

Keep in mind, Android only guarantees one or the other, so the fact that you are passing in an `EXTRA_OUTPUT` location, but also looking for the results returned in the "data" field will not work on all devices...that's not what the framework guarantees you ([docs for more info](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)).  You should only ever expect to read the file from the Uri you presented in the request, when given.  If the image is not being written there, it's because the camera app cannot access the Uri location you provided, it must be a valid path to a public location (like External Storage, not app private Internal Storage).